# How to find if a value differs from the previous line and repeat that information in next line (like a loop)?

Tags: r, difference

## Problem

The title is misleading, since it is more complex than that. I need to find the difference of value between 2 lines but from 2 different variables, and I also need to repeat that information to all rows below.

I have a list of patients, who came in and out of the hospital where I work. Sometimes, during the hospitalisation, they are moved from an unit to another unit (emergency to intensive care for example).

**I want to know how many time they actually left then returned to the hospital.**

To find that, I simply need to search for a time difference between the entry day and the previous exit day. If both are equal, then this is the same stay. If they differ, then it is another stay.

It is kinda hard to explain with my english level, so I present you an example below.

## Example

I work with `data.table`, but you can use `dplyr` if you wish to. I should be able to convert it easily.*

```
# ==== Library ====
require(data.table)

# ==== Data set ====
## The patient id, the unit id, and the entry and exit date from individuals unit
patient_id <- c(rep(x = "0034280", 4), rep(x = "0002050", 2))
unit_id    <- c(c("azr", "grt", "chd", "grt"), c("tgo", "grt"))
date_entry <- c(c("2021-07-10", "2021-07-13", "2021-07-14", "2021-07-30"),c("2021-07-29", "2021-07-30"))
date_exit  <- c(c("2021-07-10", "2021-07-14", "2021-07-25", "2021-07-30"),c("2021-07-30", "2021-07-30"))

## The variable I want to get
expected_result <- c(c(1,2,2,3), c(1,1))

## Final result expected
data_set <- data.table(patient_id, unit_id, date_entry, date_exit, expected_result)
```

As you can see, since "2021-07-13" on line 2 differ from "2021-07-10" on line 1, the expected result which indicate the number of hospitalisation for that patient increased.

## My attempt

First, I start to create a base value for the new variable

```
data_set <- data_set[
  j = stay_number := 1
]
```

Then, with the *shift* function, I can check the difference between two consecutives rows.

```
data_set <- data_set[
  j = stay_number := data.table::fifelse(test = date_entry != data.table::shift(date_exit, type = "lag"),
                                        yes  = stay_number+1,
                                        no   = stay_number),
  by = patient_id
][
  j = stay_number := data.table::fifelse(test = base::is.na(stay_number),
                                        yes  = 1,
                                        no   = stay_number)
]
```

But I do not know how to repeat the number "2" to the third row, which is the same hospitalization as the row 2. Therefore, I do not know how to find "3" on the fourth row, as it is a third hospitalization for that patient.

## Solution

Thanks to **Ronak Shah** !

```
data_set[, result := cumsum(date_entry != shift(date_exit, fill = FALSE)), patient_id]
```

Comment: Okay I believe I understand, so basically you just want to add some dummy variable for the date_exit container at the beginning(or remove the first one from date_start container), and then just minus date_entry - date_exit. Probably you would have to use some date difference function(like `difftime`). There, you will be able to compare it to zero to check if there's a difference between date left and date entry. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increment the count if `date_exit` from previous row is different than the current `date_entry` for each `patient_id`.

```
library(data.table)
data_set[, result := cumsum(date_entry != shift(date_exit, fill = FALSE)), patient_id]

#   patient_id unit_id date_entry  date_exit expected_result result
#1:    0034280     azr 2021-07-10 2021-07-10               1      1
#2:    0034280     grt 2021-07-13 2021-07-14               2      2
#3:    0034280     chd 2021-07-14 2021-07-25               2      2
#4:    0034280     grt 2021-07-30 2021-07-30               3      3
#5:    0002050     tgo 2021-07-29 2021-07-30               1      1
#6:    0002050     grt 2021-07-30 2021-07-30               1      1
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to prepare your dataset - you basically want only to compare NEXT entry with PREVIOUS exit. There will be no previous exit for first entry, so first entry could be deleted, and there will be no entry for last exit.

```
# ==== Library ====
require(data.table)

# ==== Data set ====
## The patient id, the unit id, and the entry and exit date from individuals unit
patient_id <- c(rep(x = "0034280", 4), rep(x = "0002050", 2))
unit_id    <- c(c("azr", "grt", "chd", "grt"), c("tgo", "grt"))
date_entry <- c(c("2021-07-10", "2021-07-13", "2021-07-14", "2021-07-30"),c("2021-07-29", "2021-07-30"))
date_exit  <- c(c("2021-07-10", "2021-07-14", "2021-07-25", "2021-07-30"),c("2021-07-30", "2021-07-30"))

date_exitT <- date_exit[1:(length(date_entry)-1)] #remove last exit
date_entryT <- date_entry[2:length(date_exit)] #remove first entry
```

Next, just calculate the time difference between exit and left(after the deletion the values we have to subtract lie below each other), and compare it to zero to get the truth table:

```
output<-difftime(date_exitT, date_entryT, units="days")
values<-!(output==0) #negation because we actually want zeros to be falses and all others trues
values <- c(TRUE, values) #because we want to add 1 to the result(we always starting from 1 as I see from the result)
```

And lastly, as false is treated as 0, and true as 1, we can just calculate cumulative sum.

```
vals <- cumsum(values)
```

That's basically all, you just have to split your data, so it will run this for each column(each patient). This could be done by filtering the columns with particular ID and making a temporary table for each patient(taking a subset of your set based on patient_ID)

I am not sure if I understood you well - I hope it solves your problem :)

Comment: You could probably also boost the efficiency by not using `difftime` function, just compare if strings equal - if yes, put 0, if not, put 1, and go with cumsum

Comment: Thank you for your help `@Lidbey` ! It is what I was aiming for, and the use of `cumsum` was really clever. As you said, comparing strings is faster. @ronak-shah found a perfectly clean way to do it.